# Navigation Bar Menu not opening

Tags: html, jquery, css

So basically, I took my friends website template which works on mobile and changed things and now use the template. Although, I am unable to open the mobile menu bar.

Here is the following code for the navbar

```
    <div class="contact-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 align-left">
            <head>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"></head>

                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone" style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 19px;"></i> (416) 824-5864</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> topspintennisstringing@gmail.com</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 align-right">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/Topspin_Tennis_Stringnig/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color: #000000;"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id='navbar-toggle' class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="brand">
                <a href="../index.php"><img src="assets/img/logofinal.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
         

   <li><a href="services">Services</a></li><!--
            <li><a href="index#conditions">Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>-->
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="contact" class="book">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what the problem can be because I directly copied the code although it does not work. Also, when I uploaded his website, it also did not work. There is also no bootstrap version in the bootstrap.min.css file. I also use xampp to host the site while developing.

Thank you for reading this post!

Comment: did you link [bootstrap js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#bundle)?

Comment: no, there is only a jquery.js file. but im actually not sure if the jquery is linked either

Comment: you have to link both of jquery and bootstrap js, I think it'll work

Comment: ok, i will do that now

Comment: thank you for helping

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: I need to host it but I have to wait a couple of hours before I can find out

Comment: Um it works now, but it wasnt that. For some reason, there was no bootstrap.js file. So I got my friends template again and there the bootstrap.js file was. So I added it and now it works. Thank you for your help though